# Are Shadowrun stats saved on a server?

Tags: xbox-360, achievements, games-for-windows-live, shadowrun

I just bought *Shadowrun* from Games for Windows, and I've had this game for Xbox 360 for a long time now.

I'm trying to get the achievement for playing 100 matches as each class and I was wondering if I had to play all 100 matches again on the PC or if a server keeps track of my previous amount of playtime from when I played it on the Xbox 360?

Shadowrun is one of the few games where PC and Xbox 360 user can play cross-platform, so I can hope the stats transfer between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple sources state that "Shadowrun lacks a stat-tracking system." So No, they are not saved anywhere.

Comment: I think they are saved to your gamertag profile.  A lot of games do this in fact.  Check out the issue with Seriously achievement issues on Gears of War (i.e. kills added to leaderboards, but not always saved to your profile meaning you need 13000 kills in some cases).